# iOS FMDB multithreading operation failure

Tags: ios, xcode, fmdb

yep,i try to operation database in multi-thread with fmdb.
i create a timer to work to query database with 1.5s interval in child thread.
in the same time , it may operation the database in main-thread with delete,add,edit operation.
i find the delete add edit operation may fail if the query is operating.it say the database is locked.
i dont know how fmdb work in multi-thread,this is my code:

```
-(NSArray *)list{

NSString *path = [[PathHelper cachePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/MessagesCache.db"];
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:path];
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
    [db open];
    FMResultSet *set = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM t_messagesCache ORDER BY triggerTime ASC;"];

    while (set.next) {

        MXNIMMessageModel *message = [MXNIMMessageModel new];
        message.msgType = [set intForColumn:@"msgType"];
        message.uid = [set stringForColumn:@"uid"];
        message.msg = [set stringForColumn:@"msg"];
        message.nickname = [set stringForColumn:@"nickname"]; ;
        message.name = [set stringForColumn:@"name"];
        message.url = [set stringForColumn:@"url"];
        message.ext = [set stringForColumn:@"ext"];
        message.dur = [set intForColumn:@"dur"];
        message.w = [set intForColumn:@"w"];
        message.h = [set intForColumn:@"h"];
        message.size = [set intForColumn:@"size"];
        message.lastInterval = [set intForColumn:@"lastInterval"];
        message.md5 = [set stringForColumn:@"md5"];
        message.sort = [set intForColumn:@"sort"];
        message.triggerTime = [set stringForColumn:@"triggerTime"];
        message.teamId = [set stringForColumn:@"teamId"];

        [list addObject:message];

    }
    [db close];

}];
return list;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)deleteMessageModelByUid:(NSString *)uid
```

{

```
__block BOOL result;
NSString *path = [[PathHelper cachePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/MessagesCache.db"];
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:path];
[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
    [db open];
    result = [db executeUpdateWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM t_messagesCache WHERE uid = %@",uid];
    [db close];
}];

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCD SERIAL QUEUE to keep all FBMD operations on a thread.

**First**, define a global serial queue:

```
@interface ExampleClass 
@property(nonatomic,strong) dispatch_queue_t queue;
@end

@implementation ExampleClass
//......
- (dispatch_queue_t)queue {
    if (_queue != nil) {
        _queue = dispatch_queue_create("SERIAL_QUEUE", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return _queue;
}
//......
@end
```

**Then**, operation FMDB in the queue, that will keep all operation on a thread:

```
//For list
dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
    //NSArray *list = [yourObjectForFMDB list];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //do UI operation with list
    });
});

//For deleting
dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
    //[yourObjectForFMDB deleteMessageModelByUid:@"1"];
});
```

**Theory**：dispatch_async will create a new thread to do the task, and a SERIAL QUEUE makes sure there is only one thread created.

The ExampleClass here could be a singleton for global usage.

Comment: i have a problem:result = [db executeUpdateWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM t_messagesCache"]; code like this is not immediate return result,so how can i keep correct for serial

Comment: Do you mean some tasks themselves are async?

Comment: yes, i dont know code like this: bool a = [db executeUpdateWithFormat:""] is async or sync,it returen a bool type value ,so i think it must be sync,but in my test ,it seem async. i am confuse.

Comment: Usually, it's sync if a method returns a value. And it's async if method provide a block to callback. For async situation, you could also use block callback to the method caller.

Comment: ok , so how can i use fmdb in multi-thread,i use 'inDatabase' method, but in some time insert or delete method doesnt work,even sometime it cause bad  access.do you have some practise in the case.

Answer (score 0):

We can perform any action when database is open. So in fmdb you can't do mutithread because for every query fmdb first open the db fire query &return 
the result set and then close it again.

If you need to perform then you keep you db open for both task..

Comment: ok,but i remove closed db is the same problem. it happen for small probability